# How to ask for continuous blocks (non fragmented) when appending or creating files in C?

Tags: mysql, c, database, operating-system, innodb

So i want to understand how DBMS implementation works

To give an example :

MySQL implements each tables with its own pages, which are 16KB

so each table is a file, and is a multiple of 16KB, considering how large is it and therefore how many pages it needs

Now i read somewhere that these **pages** don't get fragmented in **disk image** or **memory image**, so my question is, HOW?

how do DBMS developers tell the operating system that "hey i just added a 16KB data (page) to this file, but make this page doesn't get fragmented"

is it because the memory image doesn't actually show how bytes are really stored on disk and its logical?

or is it because these DBMSes somehow ask the O.S to make sure these chunks of 16KB bytes do not get fragmented?

and how to do this in C?

Comment: "*Now i read somewhere that these pages don't get fragmented in disk image or memory image*" Do you have a source for this? I can't even figure out what it would *mean* for a page to be fragmented in a memory image.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1742287615000584

Comment: @DavidSchwartz dont get it confused with the O.S page concepts, this is a different page that databases use, and what it would mean is lets say O.S uses block sizes of 1k, and page is 16KB, this page COULD turn into 16 parts in different places, or all in one place, but in this case all of them are together in the image for some reason.

Comment: memory mapped files, on demand paging, physical page locking, etcetera, is different between OS.  Disk image fragmentation only means something when you are worried about seek times on certain kinds of media.  On solid state devices you wouldn't worry (and sometimes have no control) of where data resides (it can even move it should a block starts to fail, get marked bad, and gets moved to a good block).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

50 years ago, your question was a hot topic in Computer Science and Engineering.  But not today.

Virtually every hard drive has an allocation unit of 512 bytes.  CDs have an AU of 2KB.  Certain SSDs, when tuned for MySQL, have an AU of 16KB.

There are many different "filesystems".  Windows has (at least) FAT-32 and NTFS.  *nix has lots.  Each FS prides itself with doing a better job at something.  But freespace management fights with allocation unit size.  Remember the hassle DOS had with it's FAT-16 while disks were getting bigger and bigger?  The "16" in the name refers to the disk having up to 2^16 blocks.  That forced a 2GB disk drive had an allocation unit of 32KB!  The typical system had a lot of little files, literally half the disk was probably wasted!

I'm talking about "Allocation Units" because that is essentially the only way to prevent the OS from thinking about scattering the blocks around the drive.

Let's look at your question from a marketing point of view.  If fragmentation is such a big deal, then

1. New, better, filesystems would come along to solve the problem -- though not necessarily in the simplistic way you mentioned.
2. Operating systems have known about the problem, so they have ways of "trying" to allocate in chunks.  But they are always willing to give you little pieces when necessary.
3. MySQL's InnoDB (circa 2000) went to a lot of effort of allocating in "extents" of 4MB(?) in hopes of getting contiguously allocated disk.  But when it failed, nothing would crash.
4. Software would bypass the problem, such as by using "raw drive access.  But notice how that is not in the forefront of "how to optimize your database"?  If even available, it is buried in the "Oh, by the way" chapter.

A few decades ago, there were some OSs that would let you pre-allocate a file that was "contiguous".  I have not heard of such recently.

Enterprise systems solved the issue by using hardware RAID controllers with Battery Backed Write Cache.  Not only would the scatter-gather be hidden from the user, but writes became 'instantaneous' because of the crash-safe cache.

SSDs don't have any seek time (unlike HDDs), so it really does not matter if a block is chopped up.  Sure, there is some code to deal with it, but that is really insignificant compared to the transfer, checksum, mutex, system call, etc, etc, times.

I have a Rule of Thumb:  If a potential optimization does not look like it will help by 10%, I drop it and move on to something else.  I suggest you move on.

Answer (score 0):

> how to do this in C:

```
int add16k(void *My16kDataChunk) {
    fd = open(“My.DataBase”, O_WRONLY|O_APPEND);
    if (fd != -1) {
         write(fd, My16kDataChunk, 16*1024);
         close(fd);
    }
    return fd != -1;
}
```

But for a data base, you might want to cache your open file descriptors, be able to write at arbitrary offsets, ensure that the data is genuinely recorded(*), etc.  Most importantly, you want to ensure that multiple requests do not interfere with each other.   In reverse you need: synchronization, fdatasync, pwrite.

> memory image doesn’t show ...
>   It is because the memory image is identical to what is on disk.   Two subsystems, the VM and FileSystem co-operate to achieve this.   If I write 16k, and the file system has to collect 4 discontiguous 4k sectors to store it, it arranges my read() and write() calls to be oblivious to this layout -- it delivers the data to and from virtually contiguous areas.   Similarly, if a 16k buffer requires 4 discontiguous 4k physical memory pages, the VM system arranges the page mappings to construct a contiguous virtual range.

That said, some file systems support mechanisms to pre-allocate physically contiguous regions of the disk [ although with volume management, SANs, virtualization this is mainly pretend ], so that the file system can achieve performance goals and the expense of portability.

(*) - this seems like a fairly simple idea, I can just call fsync(), fdatasync(), sync(), or some such.  Yeah, no. This http://blog.httrack.com/blog/2013/11/15/everything-you-always-wanted-to-know-about-fsync/ gives a pretty good treatment of it.  TL;DR - OS/FileSystem peoples loose idea of truth would make a compiler vendor blush.

Comment: So you think this is how databases achieve it too? they basically ask the O.S to allocate them a continuous 16KB of data everytime a new database page is added correct?

Comment: also how do you know the code you wrote doesn't cause fragmentation ? didn't you basically ask the O.S to give you 16KB, and O.S might have given different parts of the disk to you in total of 16KB?

Comment: "That said, some file systems support mechanisms to pre-allocate physically contiguous regions of the disk [ although with volume management, SANs, virtualization this is mainly pretend ], so that the file system can achieve performance goals and the expense of portability."

Comment: @mevets - I disagree.  I don't think that code necessarily avoids scattering the data around the disk.  The OS is obligated to write all 16KB before returning, but it is free to scatter the pieces.

Comment: yes, physically doesn’t mean physically; physically means logically physically, which might have no bearing on the underlying { electronics, magnetics, mechanics, quantum state, ... }

Answer (score 0):

In strictly-conforming C code, you can't. Standard C has a very lose concept of what a file is. Even getting the size of a file can't be done with strictly-conforming C, other than by opening a file in binary mode and reading it byte-by-byte and counting.*  There's simply no way to specify how a file will be stored in conforming C code.

So you're left with using system-dependent methods.

POSIX provides [the `posix_fallocate()` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_fallocate.html):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <fcntl.h>
>
> int posix_fallocate(int fd, off_t offset, off_t len); [Option End]
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `posix_fallocate()` function shall ensure that any required
>   storage for regular file data starting at offset and continuing for
>   len bytes is allocated on the file system storage media. If
>   `posix_fallocate()` returns successfully, subsequent writes to the
>   specified file data shall not fail due to the lack of free space on
>   the file system storage media.

Note, again, though, that there's no way to ensure the how the underlying system makes sure subsequent writes to the file will succeed.

It's still "implementation-defined" if the file space will be contiguous.  It's probably more likely that the space reserved will be allocated by the file system as a contiguous chunk, but there's absolutely no guarantees.

Linux provides [the `fallocate()` function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>    #define _GNU_SOURCE             /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
>    #include <fcntl.h>
>
>    int fallocate(int fd, int mode, off_t offset, off_t len);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> This is a nonportable, Linux-specific system call.  For the portable,
>          POSIX.1-specified method of ensuring that space is allocated for a
>          file, see `posix_fallocate(3)`.
>
> `fallocate()` allows the caller to directly manipulate the allocated
>          disk space for the file referred to by fd for the byte range starting
>          at offset and continuing for len bytes.
>
> ...

Note how this is explicitly listed as "nonportable, Linux-specific".

And even the non-portable, Linux-specific `fallocate()` function provides absolutely no guarantees about contiguous file allocation.

Because actual allocation of space is a file-system dependent operation.

XFS, for example, [tries to preallocate file space](http://xfs.org/index.php/XFS_FAQ#Q:_What_is_speculative_preallocation.3F) so data is stored in contiguous blocks.

But again, with no guarantees.

Only high-performance file systems such as Oracle's HSM (Sun's SAM-QFS) and IBM's Spectrum Scale (originally called GPFS) provide the level of control necessary for you to even have any real chance at getting contiguous allocation of space in a file.

For example, [the Oracle HSM/QFS `setfa()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E22586_01/html/E22976/glarp.html#scrolltoc):

> **NAME**
>
> ```
> sam_setfa - Sets attributes on a file or directory
> ```
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>  cc [ flag  ... ] file    ...  -L/opt/SUNWsamfs/lib  -lsam  [library ... ]
>
>  #include "/opt/SUNWsamfs/include/lib.h"
>
>  int sam_setfa(const char *path, const char *ops);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> ```
>  sam_setfa() sets attributes on a file or directory  using  a
>  SAM-QFS  system  call.  path is the file on which to set the
>  attributes.  ops is the character  string  of  options,  for
>  example:  "ds1".  Individual options are described below.
> ```
>
> **OPTIONS**
>
> ```
>  A n  Specifies the number of bytes to be allocated ahead  of
>       a write to the file.  The n must be an integer and must
>       be greater than or equal to one kilobyte and less  than
>       4  terabytes.   The n is rounded down to units of kilo-
>       bytes.  This option is only valid for a  regular  file.
>       This  option  should  be  used when writing large files
>       where more sequential  allocation  is  desired.   Note,
>       when  the  file  is  closed the blocks are reset to the
>       size of the file.
>
>       ...
>
>  l n  Specifies the number of bytes to be preallocated to the
>       file.   The n must be an integer.  This option can only
>       be applied to a regular file.  If an I/O event attempts
>       to  extend  a  file preallocated with the L option, the
>       caller receives an ENXIO error.  The l option allocates
>       using  extent  allocation.   This means striping is not
>       supported and the file is allocated on 1 disk device or
>       1  striped  group.   The  L  and l options are mutually
>       exclusive.  If the file has existing disk blocks,  this
>       option is changed to the L option.
>
>  L n  Specifies the number of bytes to be preallocated to the
>       file.   The  n must be an integer.  This option is only
>       valid for a regular file.  The L option allocates using
>       standard allocation.  This means striping is supported.
>       This also means the file can be extended.  The L and  l
>       options are mutually exclusive.
>
>       ...
> ```

Even on high-performance, complex, proprietary file systems that offer a lot of options for how files are stored on disk, it's impossible to guarantee contiguous space allocation within a file.

Which is one reason high-end database can use raw devices for data storage - it's really the only way to guarantee contiguous data storage.

* No, `fseek()`/`ftell()` is not strictly-conforming C code.  `fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_END )` is [explicitly undefined behavior on a binary stream](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note268), and [`ftell()` can't be used to get the number of bytes in a text file](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.4p2).

Comment: "Which is one reason high-end database can use raw devices for data storage - it's really the only way to guarantee contiguous data storage"-->  Can you explain this sentence a bit more? so are you saying it can be done and databases are probably using it to make sure these pages get a contiguous  blocks? I just want to know if in modern database servers, these pages get fragmented or they prevent it to speed up queries.

Answer (score 0):

> Now i read somewhere that these pages don't get fragmented in disk image or memory image, so my question is, HOW?

The database has to preallocate the files.

> how do DBMS developers tell the operating system that "hey i just added a 16KB data (page) to this file, but make this page doesn't get fragmented"

That would have to be done through system services.

> is it because the memory image doesn't actually show how bytes are really stored on disk and its logical?
>   No.
>
> or is it because these DBMSes somehow ask the O.S to make sure these chunks of 16KB bytes do not get fragmented?

Again, you have to do a contiguous extension, something that has a high probability of failing.

> and how to do this in C?

You cannot do it in standard C. However, any rationally designed operating system will have services that allow you to allocate contiguous files.